# Predator-prey pursuit-evasion via random walks on a graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a connected, undirected graph. We begin by placing $a$ predators and $b$ prey on the graph: each one is placed at a node chosen uniformly at random. Each predator and each prey takes a random walk, traversing an edge (in sync) adjacent to its current position at times $t = 0, 1, 2, \dots$, independent of the predators and prey currently on the graph. If at time $t$ a vertex is occupied by a predator and at least one prey, all of the prey on this vertex are removed from the graph. Nothing happens if a predator and a prey pass on an edge.

Suppose that $G$ is not bipartite. Then I would like to compute the expected time (or at least a satisfactory upper bound for it) that all prey are eliminated for two cases: $(1)$: $a = b = 1$ and $(2)$: $a \geq 1$, $b \geq 1$. I exclude bipartite graphs because the expected time is infinite in such a case.

I think the first case can be treated if we construct another graph $G'$ which records all the possible positions of the predator and prey (i.e., each vertex in this graph would be an ordered pair of vertices in $V$). In terms of this new graph, the single prey is eliminated when a vertex of the form $(v,v)$ is occupied. Then it would just be a matter of computing the cover time of $G'$, for which a well known upper bound exists. Could we perhaps use this result to treat the second case?

Comment: What do we know about the graph other then it is connected and non bipartite?  This is clearly going to depend on the number of nodes and also how the edges are arranged.  $k_4$ (Four nodes in a row) has a different value to  $k_{2,2}$  (Four nodes arranged in a square.

Comment: I believe those are the only two things we know about the graph.